# My custom Controller not displaying

Tags: php, magento-1.7, phpstorm

I am new to magento, I have created a custom controller but it's not getting displayed even though I configured the package in `system->configuration->general->design->package`.

my code is:

**etc/module/easylife_Test.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EasyLife_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EasyLife_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**local/easylife/Test/etc/config.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EasyLife_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </EasyLife_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>EasyLife_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

**local/easylife/Test/controller/IndexController.php file**

```
<?php

class EasyLife_Test_controller_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I ping **protocal://IPAddress/magento/test** in URL, but it is returning me a  **401 not found error**.

may I know what's wrong with this Code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that I noticed is you used package name as: easylife but it should be Easylife. So change easylife_Test.xml to Easylife_Test.xml and local/easylife/Test/etc/config.xml to local/Easylife/Test/etc/config.xml. Then check in your module in admin ->system->configuration->Advanced.

Comment: thank you for reply. I find out my error while rechecking my module. actually ins ted of controllers I created controller. now working fine.